# Dos resultados distinto de una Query en una misma salida con diferente condicion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta la cual hace la suma de una columna; tengo dos valores 1 y 2 en la condición `where "tipo_factura"`, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que pueda obtener los dos resultados en una misma salida y cada resultado con su propia leyenda?

> select  SUM(DIFERENCIA) from  TABLAA  where TIPO_FACTURA = 1

lo intente con un union all pero tal vez haya alguna forma mejor de hacerlo

> select 'FACTURA 1'  CONCEPTO,SUM(DIFERENCIA)  CIFRA from  TABLAA  where  TIPO_FACTURA = 1
>
> UNION ALL
>
> select 'FACTURA 2'  CONCEPTO,SUM(DIFERENCIA)  CIFRA from  TABLAA where
>   TIPO_FACTURA = 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si nos dices como queres que sea exactamente la salida, y especificas como son las tablas podremos ayudarte. Igual esto se soluciona con un group by.

Comment: Por favor, incluye un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas obtener con dichos datos. Pueden ser unas pocas filas, no hace falta que sean muchas, pero si que sea coherente la salida con la entrada. Un saludo.

Comment: @gbianchi es en la misma tabla pero lo que quiero es hacer la sumatoria del campo diferencia del tipo de factura 1 y 2 respectivamente y mostrarlos en una sola salida

Comment: Si. queres un group by (y si no lo googleaste a esta altura, no se que esperaste ;) ). Ahora la pregunta es, que campo queres mostrar como condicion de agrupamiento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes tener una única consulta, sin uniones, agrupando por `tipo_factura`, por ejemplo:

```
select   tipo_factura
       , sum(diferencia) Cifra
  from TablaA
 where tipo_factura in (1, 2)
 group by tipo_factura;
```

Si necesitas la columna `concepto` igual a la de la pregunta, podrías hacer:

```
select   'FACTURA ' + cast(tipo_factura as varchar) concepto
       , sum(diferencia) Cifra
  from TablaA
 where tipo_factura in (1, 2)
 group by tipo_factura;
```